# Get ORMLite DatabaseHelper in standalone class in asynch task without context

Tags: android, database, asynchronous, task, ormlite

I have android app with asynchrounous data sync from server via pressing button. However I need the button to be in all activities of app so I decided to have updateTask as standalone class.

In updateTask I download some xml data. Then use bussines object to process it and finaly let this bussines object to handle saving (or updating) to android db.

Based on ORMLite tutorials I should get databaseHelper by calling  OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class). My problem is that I need some context for OpenHelperManager which I currently don't have.

I think that best way is pass  activity's context to updateTask but how do I do it? Also isn't it weird to pass context further to bussines object which has nothing to do with any activity. And finally: what even is the context? Does it simply stand for activity parent or it has some deeper purpose?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a couple ways of doing it.  I'm pretty sure all 3 should work, but I haven't tested them myself.

### Method 1

Create a constructor for the AsyncTask that takes in the Context and store it so you can use it when it's executing.

**AsyncTask code**

```
public class DataProcessor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private Context mContext;

    public DataProcessor(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DataBaseHelper helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(mContext, DatabaseHelper.class)
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

**Implementation code (for an Activity)**

```
new DataProcessor(this).execute();
```

### Method 2

Pass the context in as an argument when you call the `execute` method

**AsyncTask code**

```
public class DataProcessor extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {

        Context context = params[0];

        DataBaseHelper helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class)
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

**Implementation code (for an Activity)**

```
new DataProcessor().execute(this);
```

### Method 3

Have a static instance of your context that the Async Task can access directly.
A way to do that can be found here: [Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

**AsyncTask code**

```
public class DataProcessor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        DataBaseHelper helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(MyApplication.getAppContext(), DatabaseHelper.class)
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

**Implementation code (for an Activity)**

```
new DataProcessor().execute(this);
```

Comment: I'm always using the Method 1 but I don't really know which one is best for optimization of code, does anyone has any idea about it ?

Comment: How do you close database connection in these cases? Should we releaseHelper in the onPostExecute?